# Why is a second cin.ignore() necessary?

Tags: c++, input

I've noticed that whenever I write a program that uses `std::cin` that if I want the user to press Enter to end the program, I have to write `std::cin.ignore()` twice to obtain the desired behavior.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    int val = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    std::cin >> val;

    std::cout << "Please press Enter to continue..." << std::endl;

    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.ignore();  // Why is this one needed?
}
```

I've also noticed that when I'm not using `cin` for actual input but rather just for the `ignore()` call at the end, I only need one.

Comment: Are you running Linux or Windows, it may be because of the CRLF problem if you running windows ...

Comment: The same "problem" happens on Solaris. It has nothing to do with CRLF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Discl: I'm simplifying what really happens.*

The first serves to purge what the extraction operator (>>) hasn't consumed.
The second waits for another \n.

It is exactly the same when we do a std::getline after an extraction: a `the_stream::ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');` is required before the call to std::getline()

Comment: Ah I see.  So if the characters you enter at the first prompt are "123\n", you're saying that operator>>() leaves that "\n" alone, and the 1st ignore() reads it; then the 2nd ignore() waits for you to press a key and reads that (the 2nd "\n").  +1.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. What platform are you running on? By definition, `ignore` extracts and discards n characters from the input stream or if it hits EOF it stops. If you do not specify any parameters it extracts 1 character. On Windows, line ending involves both a `\r` and a `\n` -- a total of two characters (a carriage return followed by a newline).

Comment: I thought that at first also, but the library is supposed to abstract whatever line ending scheme the platform uses, and your application code should only see "\n".